# Controlling which elements receive hover tooltip in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, hover, tooltip, bokeh

I'm currently trying to find a way to use an boolean array in order to decide which elements recive HoverTooltips in bokeh while only using one dictonary for the plot.

I allready tryed to use the bokeh rendering function but this didn't quite work.

```py
source.data = dict(
        x=data_source.loc[:, 'x_col_name'],
        y=data_source.loc[:, 'y_col_name'],
        color=color_selection(selected), # Translates bool to color
        alpha=alpha_selection(selected), # Translates bool to transparency
        active=selection                 # boolean array of selected elements
     )
```

Only active datapoints should recieve a HoverTooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary work-around you could hide the tooltips in a callback like this (works for Bokeh v1.3.0):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

data = dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        color=['red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red'], 
        active=[False, True, False, True, False],
     ) 

p = figure(tooltips=[('x','@x'),('y', '@y'), ('active', '@active')])
p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=10, source = data)

code_hover = '''
if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 0) {
    var active_index = cb_data.index.indices[0]   
    var data = cb_data.renderer.data_source.data
    var show_tooltip = data['active'][active_index]
    var tooltip_index = 0

    if (show_tooltip) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bk-tooltip')[tooltip_index].style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bk-tooltip')[tooltip_index].style.display = 'none';       
    }
}
'''

p.hover.callback = CustomJS(code = code_hover)

show(p)
```

Please note the `tooltip_index` in the callback. If you have more tooltips you need to change that index. See also [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!topic/bokeh/coNozpTGKng)

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 1.x there is no built-in capability to filter hover results. That feature is planned for the 2.0 release, you can follow this issue here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9087